# Unexpected "git rebase" effect?

Tags: git, git-rebase

It is `git log` result before `rebase`:

```
$ git log --branches --graph --oneline                                                 
* ea450cb (HEAD -> v1.0) combination lots of modifies..
* d602e25 nnew edit
| * 51bfb5f (master) abc added
|/  
* 11e16ef animals gg
* 78e1630 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, brc) important backup file is forced to commit.
* 7a87267 nc.txt is ignored, anymore.
* 5def0f6 (tag: v2.0) local .ignre and test *.dat files.
* 1591c3a ignoreDir directory *.dat files are ignored.
* f84ad0d log add
* ac462c0 .gitignore test.
* 4d1e437 .gitignore file is added
* b3574db hüloo
*   3389e5c merge2
|\  
| * bb64902 (origin/confl) Change line.
| * 14f7040 İnit for another conflict exercise.
* | ca51aef (tag: v1.0) Truth of line.
* | f4fcc04 Init for another conflict exercise.
|/  
*   0f251b2 Merge branch 'octodog'
```

I want to change it like (only focus at *last 3 commits*):

```
$ git log --branches --graph --oneline                                                 
* 51bfb5f (master) abc added
* ea450cb (HEAD -> v1.0) combination lots of modifies..
* d602e25 nnew edit
* 11e16ef animals gg
* 78e1630 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, brc) important backup file is forced to commit.
* 7a87267 nc.txt is ignored, anymore.
* 5def0f6 (tag: v2.0) local .ignre and test *.dat files.
* 1591c3a ignoreDir directory *.dat files are ignored.
* f84ad0d log add
* ac462c0 .gitignore test.
* 4d1e437 .gitignore file is added
* b3574db hüloo
*   3389e5c merge2
|\  
| * bb64902 (origin/confl) Change line.
| * 14f7040 İnit for another conflict exercise.
* | ca51aef (tag: v1.0) Truth of line.
* | f4fcc04 Init for another conflict exercise.
|/  
*   0f251b2 Merge branch 'octodog'
```

But when i done:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git rebase v1.0
```

It turned to:

```
$ git log --branches --graph --oneline                                                 
* 8c4a1e6 (HEAD -> master) abc added
* 22b75db animals gg
* 6f88917 important backup file is forced to commit.
* 69ef5c8 nc.txt is ignored, anymore.
* 36a270d local .ignre and test *.dat files.
* 55e7afd ignoreDir directory *.dat files are ignored.
* aac484c log add
* 5d13b95 .gitignore test.
* 51cf1e9 .gitignore file is added
* d1d37cd hüloo
| * ea450cb (v1.0) combination lots of modifies..
| * d602e25 nnew edit
| * 11e16ef animals gg
| * 78e1630 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, brc) important backup file is forced to commit.
| * 7a87267 nc.txt is ignored, anymore.
| * 5def0f6 (tag: v2.0) local .ignre and test *.dat files.
| * 1591c3a ignoreDir directory *.dat files are ignored.
| * f84ad0d log add
| * ac462c0 .gitignore test.
| * 4d1e437 .gitignore file is added
| * b3574db hüloo
| *   3389e5c merge2
| |\  
|/ /  
| * bb64902 (origin/confl) Change line.
| * 14f7040 İnit for another conflict exercise.
* | ca51aef (tag: v1.0) Truth of line.
* | f4fcc04 Init for another conflict exercise.
|/  
*   0f251b2 Merge branch 'octodog'
```

As you see from `3389e5c merge2` to  `11e16ef animals gg` , it applied commits twice.

Why it is not working as i expect? What's the way of my goal?

Comment: Please Limit the output to what is really needed for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *two* things called `v1.0`.

One is your *current branch:*

```
* ea450cb (HEAD -> v1.0) combination lots of modifies..
```

and the other is a *tag:*

```
* | ca51aef (tag: v1.0) Truth of line.
```

When you ask Git about `v1.0`, it will *usually* choose the tag, which in this case means commit `ca51aef`.  This is the case for `git rebase`.

(The `git checkout` command will choose the branch instead.)

To make what you want to happen, actually happen, you have several choices:

- name the commit by hash ID: `git rebase ea450cb`
- name the commit by a more-complete name: `git rebase heads/v1.0` or `git rebase refs/heads/v1.0`
- fix the root problem by renaming the branch: `v1.0` is not a good branch name but is a good tag name, so keep the tag, and change the branch name.

Comment: It was out of my attention, thank you. I rolled back using `reflog` and tried your way, it worked! Thus, I get that tags beat branches..